# Validate select with javascript before form submit

Tags: javascript, html

Am trying to check if a user has not selected any option from the select options list and then pass the error message to the user via a span id...else submit the form...I want javascript code that can check for empty selected index options for two select. Here is my code for that..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
 <label for="exampleInputSelect1">Select Your Stage</label>
 <select  class="form-control" name="course" id="course">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Education">Education</option>
      <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
     <option value=" Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
 </select>
 <span class="help-block" style="color:red;font-size:1em;font-family:Segoe UI" id="course_err"></span>
 </div><br/>
                                
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleInputSelect2">Select Your Stage</label>
  <select type="password" class="form-control" name="stage" id="stage">
       <option value="Y1S1">Y1S1</option>
       <option value="Y1S2">Y1S2</option>
       <option value="Y2S1">Y2S1</option>
       <option value="Y2S2">Y2S2</option>
       <option value="Y3S1">Y3S1</option>
       <option value="Y3S2">Y3S2</option>
       <option value="Y4S1">Y4S1</option>
       <option value="Y4S2">Y4S2</option>

   </select>
<span class="help-block" style="color:red;font-size:1em;font-family:Segoe UI" id="stage_err"></span>
  </div>
</form>
 <button onclick="Check()" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
<script>
function Check(){
   var c=document.getElementById("course");
    var s=document.getElementById("stage");
    if(c.options[c.selectedIndex].text==""){
        document.getElementById("course_err").innerHTML="You have to select a course";
    }else{
        alert("form is ready to submit");
    }
}
```

Am trying to check for empty selects and pevent submission until the user selects something from the option list..I need code to do that simultaneously for two selects, Thank you

Comment: there is no `x ` declaration in your code

Comment: Thanks for that, i can't believe i never thought about that

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong variable `x`, to be changed to `c`:

```js
function Check(){
   var c=document.getElementById("course");
    var s=document.getElementById("stage");
    if(c.options[c.selectedIndex].text==""){
        document.getElementById("course_err").innerHTML="You have to select a course";
    }else if(s.options[s.selectedIndex].text==""){
        document.getElementById("stage_err").innerHTML="You have to select a semester";
    } else {
        alert("form is ready to submit");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
 <label for="exampleInputSelect1">Select Your Stage</label>
 <select  class="form-control" name="course" id="course">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Education">Education</option>
      <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
     <option value=" Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
 </select>
 <span class="help-block" style="color:red;font-size:1em;font-family:Segoe UI" id="course_err"></span>
 </div><br/>
                                
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleInputSelect2">Select Your Stage</label>
  <select type="password" class="form-control" name="stage" id="stage">
       <option value="Y1S1">Y1S1</option>
       <option value="Y1S2">Y1S2</option>
       <option value="Y2S1">Y2S1</option>
       <option value="Y2S2">Y2S2</option>
       <option value="Y3S1">Y3S1</option>
       <option value="Y3S2">Y3S2</option>
       <option value="Y4S1">Y4S1</option>
       <option value="Y4S2">Y4S2</option>

   </select>
<span class="help-block" style="color:red;font-size:1em;font-family:Segoe UI" id="stage_err"></span>
  </div>
</form>
 <button onclick="Check()" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks but isn't there a way to check two selects at the same time for my form. i also need another one for the semester perse..

Comment: Using the AND / OR logic built into javscript

Comment: @CoderTimothy don't forget to accept the answer  & upvote :)